# Mechanize - Add to form post submission

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm using Mechanize to fill out a form. Part of this form is dynamic. It defaults to have 5 field options, and it then uses javascript to dynamically add additional text fields. The fields do not show up in the page source after the button is pressed, but follows the same naming patter, IE: name=options[6].

Is there a way to handle this with Mechanize? Can you manually add fields to be submitted?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I don't know what to try. Is there anyway to manipulate the POST data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to add a new control then set the value.

```
self.browser.form.new_control('text','options[5]',{'value':''})
self.browser.form.fixup()
self.browser["options[5]"] = "New option."
```